# SQL Server multiple EXEC Stored procedure and C# with XML

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a few stored procedures which I am trying to call from another stored procedure like this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @x1 XML;
DECLARE @x2 XML;
DECLARE @x3 XML;

EXEC p1 0, 2, @x1 OUTPUT
EXEC p2 0, 0, @x2 OUTPUT
EXEC p3 1, @x3 OUTPUT

DECLARE @x XML;

SET @x = (SELECT @x1, @x2, @x3) FROM XML PATH('root')
```

When I execute procedure in management studio, it returns 4 outputs in the result window. `@x1, @x2, @x3` and `@x` respectively.

But when try to read this output in .NET C# (`xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();`), it only reads the first xml from `@x1`.

I don't know how can I limit the stored procedure to only return the output of `@x`. Or do I need something else?

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT:**

Here is the first procedure:

```
@VersionID AS INT,
@xml AS XML = NULL OUTPUT

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @xml = (
SELECT
    COALESCE(VersionID, 0) AS VersionID,
    COALESCE(VersionName, '') AS VersionName
FROM
    Versions v
WHERE
    v.VersionID = @VersionID
FOR XML PATH ('Version')
);

SELECT @xml;
```

The rest look exactly the same with different tables

Comment: Please post the entire SP definition along with a call sample and a result sample. Could be related to SET NOCOUNT ON; statement.

Comment: And what with xmlReader.NextResult(), does this help?

Comment: I don't think xmlReader has a NextResult method. It's different the a SQLDataReader.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the nested sprocs? At least p1 for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SELECT @xml;` at the end of the Stored Proc is being returned as the first result set (out of several result sets). You should remove that SELECT as you are returning the value via OUTPUT param.

If the `SELECT @xml;` is required by other callers of this proc, then you can add another input param for `@SelectOutput BIT = 1` and wrap the SELECT at the end around a test of the new input param, such as:

```
IF (@SelectOutput = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT @xml;
END
```

Then in your outer proc (as shown at the top of your question), pass in a `0` for the new input param. No other callers of the proc need to be updated since the default value is to operate as it currently does.

```
EXEC p1 0, 2, @x1 OUTPUT, 0
```

Repeat the above steps (i.e. either remove final SELECT or at least wrap in an IF condition based on new, optional input param) for all sub-proc calls (i.e. p1, p2, and p3).

Finally:

- Be sure to set the value of `@x` correctly. What is posted in the question doesn't work (might even cause the proc to error) and should be: `SET @x = (SELECT @x1, @x2, @x3 FOR XML PATH('root'))`
- Make sure to actually do a `SELECT @x` in that outer proc as simply setting `@x` (assuming that it is an OUTPUT param) isn't a result set and hence not what XmlReader is looking for.

Comment: <code>SELECT @xml</code> is not required. I have removed the SELECT statement from inner procedures, it only returns the output of @xml. But now in C# code, I get this error: "Invalid command sent to ExecuteXmlReader.  The command must return an Xml result."

Comment: @huber.duber: I have updated my answer to be clearer about the need to do this for all sub-proc calls, not just `p1`. I suspect there are still issues in either, p2, p3, or both. Also, just FYI, inline code format is back-quote "`".

Comment: @huber.duber: a few more edits as I noticed a syntax error in your final `SET @x`

Comment: Yep. This is what I was getting at when I asked for the contents of the nexted sprocs.

Comment: @KarlKieninger: yes, that was _definitely_ required, yet missing, info (which is why I +1 your comment :-).